# How to install a package to python which is not default

Tags: python, python-3.4, zlib

I am trying to add zlib package to my python. However, after I install it using "yum install zlib", only the default python (which is python 2.4.3) can import it. While the other python (3.4.4) still cannot use zlib.

When I try to import zlib in python 3.4.4 by

> import zlib

It displays

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "< stdin >", line 1, in
>
> ImportError: No module named 'zlib'

My question is, how can I install package to python which is not default?

PS. I installed both zlib and zlib-devel

Thanks

Comment: `"yum install zlib"` installs library for Linux, not module for Python.

Comment: I think you might need `zlib-devel`

Comment: module `zlib` is in python standard library. See: [zlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html). Do you get error when you `import zlib` ? Always add full error message in question.

Comment: I installed zib-devel as well and still have the problem. The error information is updated. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install the `zlib-devel` package as well: `yum install zlib-devel`.
Otherwise you need to post the full error message when you try to run `import zlib`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I've posted the error message. And I did install zlib-devel but seems it doesn't fix the problem